# @autoreleasepool expected expression before @ token

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting, nsautoreleasepool

I have an iOS project which uses ARC, and I'm receiving an error related to the the way I'm creating the app's @autoreleasepool.

In in main.m I have a small snippet of code such that:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"MyAppDelegate");
    }
}
```

And I receive the error message:
**error: expected expression before '@' token**

However if I revert to the old style of creating an autoreleasepool:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
    [pool release];
    return retVal;
}
```

I receive various errors related to ARC in the IDE specifically:

1. NSAutoreleasePool is unavailable: not available in automatic reference counting mode
2. ARC forbitds explicit message send of 'release'

However when I attempt to build, it builds successfully.

**Where is the conflict?

How can I get it to use the new style of creating the auto-release pool?**

Comment: Autorelease pool error: are you compiling the code using `gcc` (as opposed to `clang`)? ARC errors: there the compiler is right.

Comment: You might want to select the target in the top of the left panel and click the "Validate Settings" button.

Comment: import your appDelegate, and change `@"MyAppDelegate"` to `NSStringFromClass([MyAppDelegate class]`

Answer (score 2):

Be sure you are set to be using the Clang complier (Apple LLVM) and not GCC:

[image]

Then write you main.m similarly to this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```